# MySQL UNION query separation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query that uses a UNION:

```
$this->db->query('
        SELECT DISTINCT users.user_pic, users.id, users.username, contacts.accepted 
        FROM users
        LEFT JOIN contacts ON users.id = contacts.user_1
        WHERE contacts.user_2 = ' . $this->session->userdata('user_id') . '
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT DISTINCT users.user_pic, users.id, users.username, contacts.accepted 
        FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN contacts ON users.id = contacts.user_2
        WHERE user_1 = ' . $this->session->userdata('user_id')
);
```

Is there a way to see if the sessions 'user_id' was encountered in **contacts.user_1** or **contacts.user_2**? Maybe by changing the query, or if i can use some **if** statements in the view?

Thanks in advance

George

Comment: Why don't you just make two separate queries? Gosh, why is everyone so obsessed with shoving *everything* into one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can add another field to select , that you can recognise like (1,2)

```
$this->db->query('
        SELECT 1 as table_id,DISTINCT users.user_pic, users.id, users.username, contacts.accepted 
        FROM users
        LEFT JOIN contacts ON users.id = contacts.user_1
        WHERE contacts.user_2 = ' . $this->session->userdata('user_id') . '
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT 2 as table_id,DISTINCT users.user_pic, users.id, users.username, contacts.accepted 
        FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN contacts ON users.id = contacts.user_2
        WHERE user_1 = ' . $this->session->userdata('user_id')
);
```

Comment: +1 good solition, an alias (as "table_id") will make this query more usable.

Comment: Had to change the syntax to SELECT DISTINCT 1 as table_id. And it works perfectly. Thanks for the quick answer :) George

Answer (score 1):

I typically use:

$id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

then use $id in the query. Reads cleaner and on MySQL at least, if the query fails, it lists the value of $id. Never tried calling the session in the query before.